# Help understanding microcontroller-to-transformer circuit

Tags: microcontroller, transformer

I have had a hack and understanding how a circuit board works and have hit a snag in understanding one part. The circuit is driven by a microcontroller and has two isolated, biphasic AC outputs. The outputs are taken across the secondaries of two transformers (assuming they are audio transformers, but I might be wrong). In addition to generating the output signals, the microcontroller additionally drives an LED indicator for each of the two outputs; the brightness varies depending on the output.

I have attached the circuit for one of the outputs as I have traced it on the circuit board. I am having issues in understanding what exactly the circuit is doing, what role each transistor is playing, and how a biphasic AC signal is generated.

All NPNs are BC548 and the PNP is a BD438. The two 'L' lines are microcontroller pins using 5V logic.

[image]

Comment: The two NPN transistors, with the 30 ohm resistor between the collectors, can't possibly do anything useful. Please re-check the circuit. (and when you re-draw it, please put reference designators (Q1, R1, etc) on the components, for easier discussion (or disection) of the circuit.)

Comment: There may also be an error in the base circuit of the PNP transistor, either there is something missing, or the middle NPN is shown with incorrect connections.

Comment: CCTt is wrong as others have said. Giving us the bigger picture as well as detail may help. | Biphasic is not obviously a useful term as used. | Name transistors Q1 Q2 Q3 keft to right" Swap Q2 c and E. Q1 enables signal input from Q2. Q2 lights LED with varying input and modulates Q3. If Q3 is driven not in saturation audio is produced n load based om=n Q2 drive.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have the second transistor's Collector and Emitter swapped. Here is your circuit corrected and rearranged slightly to make its operation more obvious.

[image]

The 10k resistor and 47uF capacitor smooth out the LED PWM waveform to produce a DC voltage on the Base of Q2.

When Q1 is turned on it pulls Q2 Emitter low through the 30 Ohm resistor, turning on Q2 and causing current to flow from +12V down through Q3 Base, Q2 Collector-Emitter, 30 Ohm resistor and Q1 Collector-Emitter to ground. This current is then amplified by Q3 and and fed into the transformer.

Higher PWM ratio increases LED brightness and also raises the voltage on Q2 Base, providing more drive current to Q3 and making the output louder.

Comment: So as I understand it, Q1 is used to pass the PWM signal to Q3 via Q2? What is the reason for Q1 even being in the circuit; wouldn't tying the emitter of Q2 to ground achieve the same thing; that is, the PWM would modulate Q3? Could a use be to allow the LED to be modulated without driving the output? That is, have the LED PWM'd but Q2 off such that the signal does not modulate Q3. For example, to flash to indicate an error without pulsating the output.

Comment: Poor answer. What would be the point of sending essentially DC signals (less than 0.5 Hz) through a transformer?

Comment: I presume the signal generated by the microcontroller is an audio frequency square wave or modulated PWM, which is fed into Q1 to create pulses of current in the transformer primary winding. The secondary output is AC due to transformer action. LED PWM is used to vary the DC bias on Q2, therefore controlling the strength of the current pulses and loudness of the output.